# Operation on mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

I have the following MySQL table

```
ArticleId | AuthorId | Author | ArticleScore
----------|----------|--------|-------------
0         |0         |Albert  |0.2
0         |1         |Bob     |0.2
0         |2         |Chris   |0.2
1         |0         |Albert  |0.5
1         |1         |Chris   |0.5
2         |0         |Chris   |0.7
```

I want to get the following table where AuthorScore is the sum of articleScore for all articles the author wrote, divided by the number of articles.

```
Table Authors

Author | AuthorScore
-------|------------
Albert | (0.2 + 0.5)/2
Bob    | 0.2
Chris  | (0.2 + 0.5 + 0.7)/3
```

How do I get the table above in mysql language?
I can write a loop in java:

```
for (String author: authorList){
    double sum = 0.0;
    double autScore =0.0;
    List<Double> results = em.createQuery("SELECT ArticleScore FROM Table WHERE Author ='" + author +"'").getResultList();

    for (double artScore: results){
        sum += artScore;
    }

    autScore = sum / results.size();
    Table t = new Table();
    t.setAuthor(author);
    t.setAuthorScore(autScore);
    em.persist();
}
em.flush();
```

But this is quite inefficient due to the two loops, and there are a million articles with multiple authors.
Is there some way this can be done in MySQL??

I think it might be along the lines of

```
SELECT sum(t.ArticleScore) / number of rows FROM Table t JOIN Authors a ON (t.author = a.author) WHERE  t.author = a.author
```

but I don't know how to do the math operations to get sum and no of rows...

Answer (score 1):

You should perform this entirely in SQL using the [`avg`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) aggregate function:

```
select author, avg(articlescore) from your_first_table group by author;
```

You can then use the results as you wish - insert them into another table as you've mentioned, however I would recommend just re-running this simple query or creating a view instead.